# Can't open dropdown menu using querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript

I have a mobile navigation with two dropdown menus. Here is the markup of the nav:

```
<div id="mobile-menu" class="mobile-menu container fixed">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#">Articles <i class="bi bi-chevron-down"></i></a>
                            <ul class="submenu hidden">
                                <li><a href="#">Submenu item 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Submenu item 2</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>

                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#">My account <i class="bi bi-chevron-down"></i></a>
                            <ul class="submenu hidden">
                                <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

The dropdown menus should open/expand when clicked. Originally I grabbed the dropdown and submnenu classes like this:

```
const mobileDropdown = document.querySelector(".dropdown");
const mobileSubMenu = document.querySelector('.submenu');
```

and used an eventlistener to toggle the "hidden" class which is just a display:none

```
mobileDropdown.addEventListener('click', () => {
    mobileSubMenu.classList.toggle('hidden');
});
```

The problem with this is that this will only open the first dropdown menu and I cannot open the second.

When I try to use querySelectorAll instead of just querySelector then i get thiserror:

> Uncaught typeError addEventListener is not a function

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55667793/uncaught-typeerror-input-addeventlistener-is-not-a-function) I read that with querySelectorAll I need to use a for or foreach loop.

but i think I'm messing it up. I tried this:

```
const mobileDropdown = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown");
const mobileSubMenu = document.querySelector('.submenu');

mobileDropdown.forEach(md => md.addEventListener('click', () => {
    mobileSubMenu.classList.toggle('hidden');
}));
```

Now I don't get an error, I can open the first dropdown menu, but when I try to open the second dropdown menu, the first one opens. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If this is your whole code, you only defined a clickEvent for `mobileDropdown`, not for `mobileSubMenu`

Comment: @Marius Thanks for the reply. Yes, this is my whole code. Do I need a clickevent on the mobileSubmenu? my goal is if I click on the "dropdown" li the submenu should open. So I only need a click event on the mobileDropdown. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is that each `mobileDropdown`'s clickEvent was linked to the first `submenu`, you should link `mobileDropdown`'s clickEvents to their `submenu` children like that

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown").forEach(md => md.addEventListener('click', () => {
  md.querySelector(".submenu").classList.toggle('hidden');
}));
```

```css
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="mobile-menu container fixed" id="mobile-menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#">Articles <i class="bi bi-chevron-down"></i></a>
            <ul class="submenu hidden">
                <li><a href="#">Submenu item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu item 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>

        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#">My account <i class="bi bi-chevron-down"></i></a>
            <ul class="submenu hidden">
                <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution. You have to listen to the 'click' event for "submenu" on the element of "dropdown".

```
const mobileDropdown = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown");

  mobileDropdown.forEach((md) => {
    md.addEventListener("click", () => {
      const mobileSubMenu = md.querySelector(".submenu");
      mobileSubMenu.classList.toggle("hidden");
    });
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

mobileSubMenu always the first!

Comment: I'm pretty sure this answer won't help anyone, add explanation and a code sample would be great